# Can I get the actual type of a union type variable?

Tags: ballerina

Suppose I have a code snippet like below:

```
var value = foo(key);

match value {
    int intVal => return intVal;

    string|float|boolean|map|() x => {
        error err = { message: "Expected an 'int', but found '<type_of_x>'"  };
        throw err;
    }
}
```

`foo()` returns a union: `int|string|float|boolean|map|()`

In the above case, I'm expecting the return value to be of type 'int' and want to print an error if not, saying an `int` was expected but found `type_of_x` instead. Can this be done in Ballerina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ballerina language does not have an operator similar to `typeof` at the moment. However, I can suggest an obvious, workaround extending Nuwan's solution.

```
function bar () returns int {
    var value = foo();

    string typeName;
    match value {
        int intVal => return intVal;
        string => typeName = "string";
        float => typeName = "float";
        boolean => typeName = "boolean";
        map => typeName = "map";
        () => typeName = "nil";
    }

    error err = { message: "Expected an 'int', but found '" + typeName + "'"  };
    throw err;
}

function foo() returns int|string|float|boolean|map|() {
    return "ddd";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
function main(string... args) {
    var value = foo();
    match value {
        int val => {
            io:println(val);
        }
        any x => {
            error err = { message: "Expected an 'int', but found 'any'"  };
            throw err;
        }
    }
}

function foo() returns(any) {
    any myInt = "hello";
    return myInt;
}
```

Right now you cannot do `typeof` and tell the type, however foo() should be typed, and therefore you should know the options available. Therefore you can match against them.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add one more point - a given value can be of any number of types in Ballerina. That is because a type is a set of values and nothing prevents the same value being in more than one set.

Therefore the idea of "typeof" is really not possible.

Comment: Theoretically, yes, that won't be possible. But practically, this is not the case, because the value, whatever it is, will have a certain type when it is created right? For example, in the code snippet Sameera posted, `foo()` returns a string. Internally, this will be represented by a `BString` object.